# WPF MediaElement ActualWidth and ActualHeight is always zero

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, mediaelement, actualwidth, actualheight

For some unknown reason I cannot get my `MediaElement` to show up when I use it in a `ControlTemplate`.

I have installed snoop and I have determined that the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` is always zero, if I put the same media element on the main window just randomly placed, it **does** show.

So, why the heck would it always be zero?? This is killing me!!

here is my xaml in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="frostElement" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Stretch="Fill"
        LoadedBehavior="Play"
        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
        Margin="0,0,0,26.083" 
        Source="../Images/ice.mpg"/>
```

Also, if I set the width and height manually, it still doesnt show up.

Comment: Can you show a little more of the XAML or a reproducible sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah! I figured it out, it was a resource issue, I put in the full path to the file (c:..blah) and it worked.